# What does the word 'sport' mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the word 'sport' mean in the following sentence?

**The day at school begins at 8:00am, when all the students sport sleepy faces and bleary eyes.**

I don't quite understand, can you make up another sentence with the same meaning?

Comment: The duplicate is the first thing on the Related list. Please search the site next time before asking. Also, please look up a word’s meaning in a dictionary first.

Answer (score 1):

It means "wear", in your example. "He's sporting those new Nike shoes." "That's quite a large hat that she is sporting today." 
from wiki
verb
1.
wear or display (a distinctive or noticeable item).
"he was sporting a huge handlebar mustache"
synonyms:   wear, have on, dress in

Hope this helps.

Comment: The duplicate is the first thing on the Related list. Please search the site next time before answering.

Answer (score 0):

It means 'display', in a slightly jolly sense. Traditionally, people would talk about a man sporting a beard or a distinctive necktie, for example. You wouldn't normally say 'sporting sleepy faces' so that's being used jokingly.

Comment: The duplicate is the first thing on the Related list. Please search the site next time before answering.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know we were supposed to check for duplicates before *answering* as well as before posting.

Comment: As Dan Bron has said, 'Answering off-topic questions on the ... site sends the wrong message to the user-base.' Rathony has added 'We do not encourage an answer to an off-topic question. If you want to help the Original Poster, please post it as a comment.' John Lawler has levelled the complaint: 'I've answered this question several dozen times before here, and I get tired of fussing with the Official Answer stuff. Nobody ever checks them[; people] just keep asking the same questions.'  ...

Comment: And Janus Bahs Jacquet has stated: '[Y]ou  should always keep in mind the possibility of duplicates when reading (and answering) a question, and consider how likely a question is to be a duplicate.' Checking the 'Related' list seems a given.

Comment: Thanks, @EdwinAshworth. I feel stupid now. I'll stop answering via my iPhone till I can see this 'Related' list.